# How to ordering the create_date and update_date in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

In my database, there is a table like this

```
student
=======
name
create_date timestamp current_timestamp
update_date timestamp null
```

The update date is default null, only when there is update the update_date will be set the timestamp.

The problem is , I would like to order the record by the date, if there is update_date, I would like to use the update_date, if update_date is null , then use the create_date

How to change the query from simply

```
Select name from student order_by create_date desc
```

to fulfill my case?

Thanks a lot

Comment: On a different note, I would suggest setting the update_date to create_date the first time, and let it be updated everytime thereupon on an update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an expression to return the specified value

An ANSI-standard expression would be

```
CASE WHEN update_date IS NOT NULL THEN update_date ELSE create_date END
```

In MySQL, we have several functions that can return an equivalent result:

```
IF(update_date IS NOT NULL, update_date, create_date)
```

or

```
IFNULL(update_date,create_date)
```

or

```
COALESCE(update_date,create_date)
```

Use an expression like one of those in the ORDER BY clause

```
ORDER BY IFNULL(update_date,create_date) DESC
```

Comment: have you work on the codeigniter before, the $this->db->order_by('ifnull(update_date,create_date)','DESC'); cause sql error, do you have any idea to escape the field name? thanks

Comment: In CodeIgniter, I think you can pass a custom string, but I think the  `DESC` keyword is part of the string, not a separate argument. Try: `->order_by('IFNULL(update_date,create_date) DESC');`